# Using chrome storage to store textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a chrome extension. Right now, I'm trying store text from textarea into chrome.storage, and have the text load from chrome.storage into textarea when the extension reloads, so that the text is saved.

Popup.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

    //load text into chrome.storage when button is clicked
    $("#buttn").click(function(){
        var websites=$("textarea").val()
        //store the blocked websites
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"blocked":websites},function(){        
        })


    })
    //I'm not sure how to change the textarea from chrome storage.
    chrome.storage.sync.get('blocked', function(items) {
        $("#blockedWebsites").text(items.blocked);
      })



    })
```

popup.html:

```
    <html>


    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>

    <h1>Blocked Websites </h1>

    <form id="form1" >
        <textarea id = "blockedWebsites" rows="4" cols="50">
        </textarea>

    </form>

    <button id="buttn" type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>


    </html>
```

Comment: If you use the key `{"blocked":websites}` to store your info - can you use it to retrieve it?

Comment: Woops, I was using the wrong key in sync.get .But it still doesn't work?